# Changing UIImage randomly after 2 seconds in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, random, uiimage, xcode5

I have an array of images. And I am trying to change the images randomly after 2 seconds.

```
-(void)loadImage
{

  for(int i =0;i<=[imageArray count];i++)
  {
    imageView.image=[imageArray objecyAtIndex:i];
  }
}
-(void)viewDidload
{
   imageTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0 target:self selector:@selector(loadImage) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
}
```

But it is not working for me . It will be great appreciable if any one help to do this. Thanks .

Comment: dont use for loop. take index variable and call method after 2 s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make some changes in your loadImage method. You have to generate random number and set a range of the random numbers. I tried like this and it worked for me.

```
  -(void)loadImage
   {

     NSString *max=@"3";
     NSString *min=@"0";


     int randNum = rand() % ([max intValue] - [min intValue]) + [min intValue];

     _changeableImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:randNum]];

    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
      {
         [super viewDidLoad];
          _changeableImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"program.jpg"];
          imageArray=[[NSMutableArray   alloc]initWithObjects:@"corporate.jpg",@"district.jpg",@"program.jpg", nil];
          imageTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0 target:self selector:@selector(loadImage) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
      }
```

I hope it will for for you.

Answer (score 2):

modify your code in following way ..

```
-(void)viewDidload
    {
       index = 0; //index should be instance variable
       imageTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0 target:self selector:@selector(loadImage) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
    }

    -(void)loadImage
    {
        if(index != imageArray.count-1)
       {
        imageView.image=[imageArray objecyAtIndex:index];
        index++;
       }
       else
      {
        [imageTimer invalidate];
      }
    }
```

Comment: instead of invalidate the timer you set index value to 0 so that repeatedly change from first image.

Comment: Yes if you want to make it happen repeatedly you can do that @NitinGohel

Comment: i know that i just telling you that not asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
    -(void)loadImage
{

 NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [imageArray count];
  imageView.image = imageArray[randomIndex];
[self performSelector:@selector(loadImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}
-(void)viewDidload
{
  [self performSelector:@selector(loadImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `loadImage` method does not select a random image from the array. What it actually does is iterate through every single member in the array and assign them to the image view one by one every time it is run.

To set a random image each time the method is called, your method should look like this:

```
-(void)loadImage
{
  NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [imageArray count];
  imageView.image = imageArray[randomIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that whenever the timer fires, the whole loop in `loadImage` is executed, so that your image is always the last image of the array.
You have to define a property that holds e.g. the index of the currently displayed image. In `loadImage`, you had to increment then this index (modulo the array size), and assign the next image to your `imageView`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because every time `loadImage` is called you loop through and set every image in the array and therefore always end up with the last image in the array. Try something more like this:

```
-(void)loadImage{

int randNum = arc4random() % imageArray.count;
imageView.image=[imageArray objecyAtIndex:randNum-1];

}//end method
```